# How to update MySQL table column by joining with another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, left-join

I have 2 MySQL tables.

Table_1 (to be updated):

```
ID LINK NEW_ID
 1 4866
 2 1790
 3 7723
```

Table_2 (to be joined):

```
ID LINK
47 1790
49 4866
51 7723
```

I want to update Table 1 by adding the ID from Table 2 into the "NEW_ID" column. There is a reason for it rather than have the tables joined going forward.

I tried a couple of MySQL queries, the latest of which looks like this. I get errors with it.

```
$query_string = '
  UPDATE Table_1
  SET NEW_ID = (
    SELECT Table_2.ID
    FROM Table_2
    LEFT JOIN Table_1 ON Table_1.LINK = Table_2.LINK
  )
';
mysqli_query( $GLOBALS['db_link'], $query_string ) or die( mysqli_error( $GLOBALS['db_link'] ) );
```

**Error**
You can't specify target table 'Table_1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: *I get errors with it*...what errors? I don't see any.

Comment: It is bad practice to use a join to limit a queries results. If you want to just limit the results, use the where clause. `WHERE LINK=Table_1.LINK`

Comment: you're doing a select from table_1 in the subquery, which means it's effectively locked from the perspective of the outer `update`. You could just do the join at the update level. `update table_1 set new_id=table_2.id left join table_2 on table_1.link = table_2.link`

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Table_1 a
JOIN Table_2 b
   ON a.LINK = b.LINK
set a.NEW_ID = b.ID
where a.LINK=b.LINK;
```